# How to make one column of sql as Hyperlink in C#.Net

Tags: c#

Want to show on column as hyperlink (for example : the display text should be click here and on clicking the hyperlink one url should open. could you please help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it with asp.net, I guess.

```
<Columns>
<!-- first column-->
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" /> 

<!-- second column-->
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />       

<!-- third column-->
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Town" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" /> 

<!-- fourth column as hyperlink -->
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Details.aspx?Id={0}&Name={1}&Country={2}",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Id").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Name").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Country").ToString())) %>'
                Text="View Details" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

you can check the this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-bind-and-pass-query-string-in-HyperLink-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: As I have used grid view in asp.net and I want that my fourth column which is coming from sql database should be hyperlink. So in that case what should be the way to make my fourth column as hyperlink

Comment: You can find the same example on the link I mentioned, I just brought the block of code from there to here. Go through that example and you will understand how to do it.